# 「予習」はどういう意味ですか。

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, usage, phrases

[image]

what is the usage of the word [よしゅう] in Japanese. What is the best answer out of these four answers given.

Comment: Did you look up a dictionary? https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BA%88%E7%BF%92

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please help me understand \[予習\]{よ・しゅう}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16048/please-help-me-understand-%e4%ba%88%e7%bf%92%e3%82%88-%e3%81%97%e3%82%85%e3%81%86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 予習 means "preparatory study" or "preparation for a lesson." It is used to refer to the act of studying or reviewing material in advance in order to be better prepared for a lesson or class (or sometimes a business meeting). This can help you understand the material more easily during the actual lesson and be more actively engaged in class discussions.

The opposite of it is 復習. It refers to the act of studying or reviewing material after a lesson or class.

In your case, Sentence 1 is the correct answer. Sentence 2 does not make sense because what you do after a class is not 予習 but 復習. Sentence 3 seems totally irrelevant to studying (and a busy businessperson has no time do 予習 every day). Sentence 4 is not correct, either, because we don't usually use 予習 for exams (preparation for an exam is 試験勉強).